# Regex to handle a dynamic set of delimters

Tags: regex

Im writing a parser and need to handle escaping characters via regex, if possible.

Given a sample string of with the escape character of '\' and a delimiter of '&':

```
TestSection1&TestSection2\\&TestSection3\&TestSection4
```

I would like to be able to split on a valid '&', that is to say not an & that is escaped. So the above example would come out something like this:

1. TestSection1
2. TestSection2\
3. TestSection3\&TestSection4

Ive tried a quite a few regex that Ive tried to muddle together but no luck. Does anyone have any insight on how one can accomplish this, or if its even possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this double lookbehind based regex:

```
(.+?)(?:(?<!(?<!\\)\\)&|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dH8lF1/1)

`(?:(?<!(?<!\\)\\)&|$)` means match `&` or end anchor if `&` is not preceded by a single `\`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. Ill definately look into this one a bit and break it down.